# How to find value inside array of object with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have events system with different role for each event (same user could be different role in different events).
I created collection of the users and this is the schema that i used:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },

    permissions: [{
        eventId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false, ref: 'Event' },
        role: { type: String, required: false }
    }]
    },
    {timestamps: true}
);
```

For check if the user is allowed to get this event I created middleware that need to check if the eventId is exist in the User collection under "permissions"

so this is the code that I was create:

```
const authorization = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const eventId = req.params.id;
        
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
        const tokenDecoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        const userId = tokenDecoded.id
        console.log(userId)

        const userPermissionCheck = await User.find({ _id: userId, 'permissions.eventId': { $in: eventId } } );
        console.log(userPermissionCheck)
        

        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'Auth failed.' })
    }
}
```

My problem is that my find function in the authorization middleware is not working...
What the correct way to search key of object in array with mongoose?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are on the right track from your code, but you do not need the $in operator. You should be able to do the following:

```
 const userPermissionCheck = await User.find({ _id: userId, 'permissions.eventId': eventId });
```

Comment: Even when I run this command nothing is found even though it exists...

Comment: Have you console logged req.params.id to make sure you are getting the correct eventId?